# python subprocess & popen invalid syntax

Tags: python, bash, pipe, subprocess, popen

I am new to scripting. I have this line in bash I'm trying to write in python.

```
numcpu = ($(cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'physical id' | awk '{print $NF}' | sort | uniq | wc -l))
```

I have tried using sub and popen and couldnt get it to work. Here's the line:

```
numcpu = sub.Popen('($(cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'physical id' | awk '{print $NF}' | sort | uniq | wc -l))',stdout=sub.PIPE,stderr=sub.PIPE)
```

It keeps throwing errors. Any ideas on what the problem is or another way I could do it? I know maybe importing and calling os?

I am using Python v2.6 and I can't upgrade.

Comment: So how should Python know where the string starts or ends if you use the same quotes as are contained in the string?

Comment: Also, when asking for help with an error, *include the error message*. For Python, that means the full traceback should be included in your question, so we don't have to guess at the error you are getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So how should Python know where the string starts or ends if you use the same quotes as are contained in the string? Switch to using `"` double quotes to enclose your shell command.

Also, you'll need to tell `subprocess` to use a shell to run your command, otherwise it'll just try to run the command directly (and thus not support shell syntax):

```
numcpu = sub.Popen("($(cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'physical id' | awk '{print $NF}' | sort | uniq | wc -l))",
                   shell=True, stdout=sub.PIPE, stderr=sub.PIPE)
```

You may want to just read from `proc/cpuinfo` directly, and process that in Python:

```
cpu_ids = set()
with open('/proc/cpuinfo') as cpuinfo:
    for line in cpuinfo:
        if 'physical id' in line:
            cpu_ids.add(line.rsplit(None, 1)[-1])
numcpu = len(cpu_ids)
```

Comment: **+1m**! thank you Martijn; the way you describe parts of the code helped me understand the code syntax. Not everyone (including me) is professional to understand the basics of the codes. The way you answered this question was great. Thank you.